# How to initialize var outside foreach

Tags: c#, list, initialization, var

I want to initialize var outside the foreach loop.

Here is my code:

```
public List<Course> GetCourse()
    {
        IList<Semester> semesters = Semester.Get();     

        foreach (Semester sm in semesters)
        {
            IList<CourseInstance> courseInstances = CourseInstance.Get(sm[0].SemesterId);
            var courseInfos = from c in courseInstances
                                  select new Course { Code = c.Course.Code, Name = c.Course.Name };
        }

        return courseInfos.ToList();
    }
```

How do I initialize courseInfos out side the foreach loop? I try to initialize with null give me error!

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve with this code?

Comment: You are not using `sm` inside the loop - why?

Comment: it look like a school assignment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:

If you want to map SemesterName to a list of courses, I would recommend a dictionary.

```
 semesters.ToDictionary(semester => semester.Name, semester => 
                        semesters.SelectMany(sid => 
                                       CourseInstance.Get(sid.SemesterId))
                        .Select(c => new Course 
                        {Code = c.Course.Code, Name = c.Course.Name}).ToList())
```

This will create a `Dictionary<string, List<Course>`  This is nearly identical to the code below, except that it maps the semester.Name as the key.  This would, of course, mean you have to have unique semester names, otherwise the dictionary can't be created.

---

You are reinitializing courseInfos every time you loop in the foreach, so you will only get a list of the last semesterId.

You can write a linq query that does this all in one line for you.

```
return semesters.SelectMany(sid => CourseInstance.Get(sid.SemesterId))
                           .Select(c => new Course { Code = c.Course.Code, 
                                           Name = c.Course.Name }).ToList()
```

To break it down,

```
.SelectMany(sid => CourseInstance.Get(sid.SemesterId))
```

does the same thing as the foreach.  It will return an `IEnumerable<CourseInstance>`.

After that, you are calling

```
 .Select(c => new Course { Code = c.Course.Code, Name = c.Course.Name })
```

on the result that we got in the last section; it returns an `IEnumerable<Course>` that you turn into a list.

SelectMany works similar to Select except it will take each `IEnumerable<Course>` and flatten it into one sequence instead of `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Course>>`

Comment: What will be the return type if I want to output Course and Semester entity?

Comment: What do you mean?  Do you mean to map each course to its individual semester?

Comment: Well I have Semester -> Course one to many relationship. For example I want to return courseName and SemesterName. My Return Type is List<Course>. What will be the return type to retrun CourseName and SemesterName?

Comment: If you want a one to many relationship that maps Semester names to a list of courses, I would recommend a dictionary.  See above.

Answer (score 1):

var infers the type from the value you are initialising with, so initialising with null will never work. Everything else will.

I believe the Linq statement you want is

```
var courses = semesters
    .SelectMany( s => CourseInstance.Get(s.SemesterId)
    .Select( c => new Course ( Code = c.Course.Code, Name = c.Course.Name ) )
    .ToList();
```

Comment: I get error with your code. Error: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'Semester'

Comment: With your code, How do I loop through the semester if the var courses in the loop?

Comment: You don't need the [0], you want to loop on every Semester, not just the first.

Comment: Don't understand your second question

Answer (score 0):

The answer is:

```
IEnumerable<Course> courseInfos = null;

foreach (Semester sm in semesters)
{
    IList<CourseInstance> courseInstances = CourseInstance.Get(semesters[0].SemesterId);
    courseInfos = from c in courseInstances
                  select new Course { Code = c.Course.Code, Name = c.Course.Name };
}
return courseInfos.ToList();
```

However, you are discarding everything but the final iteration of the `foreach`. Is this what you meant to do?

Answer (score 0):

why not just initialize the first instance of courseInfo with the first semester and then iterate over Semesters, is there a reason you need to initialize courseInfo before the foreeach?

Answer (score 0):

may be this help. Collecting course info in each iteration.

```
  public List<Course> GetCourse()
        {
        IList<Semester> semesters = Semester.Get();

        List<Course> courseInfos = new List<Course>();
        foreach (Semester sm in semesters)
            {
            IList<CourseInstance> courseInstances = CourseInstance.Get(sm.SemesterId);
            IEnumerable<Course> result = from c in courseInstances
                              select new Course { Code = c.Course.Code , Name = c.Course.Name };
            courseInfos.AddRange(result);
            }

        return courseInfos;
        }
```